# Delphi form menus

Tags: user-interface, delphi

So I have two menu's. When I click a button on menu 1, it creates menu 2, then menu 1 hides itself. After that I want to go back to menu 1 and hide menu 2.
How do I keep a reference to menu 1 in menu 2? Then if I want to go back to menu 2 I don't want to create a new instance, I want to use the already created one. How do I do that?

I know this may be easy but I find Delphi extremley confusing and can't seem to find a way out of it.

Thanks!

Comment: By "menu", do you mean "form" (or "window")? A "menu" is a thing like the "File", "Edit", "View" at the top of the window or the thing that pops up when you right-click something.

Comment: If you mean "forms", then do this: (1) Create a new VCL app. (2) You get a main form for free. (3) Create a new form (File > New in the IDE's menu). (4) When editing the main form, press Alt+F11 to include the new unit. (5) When editing the new form, press Alt+F11 to include the main form. (6) Now you can use the name of form A in unit B and vice versa. Try `Form2.Show; Hide` in the first form and similarly in the second (`Form1.Show; Hide`).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean *Main menu* when you say "form menu" then you can have only one actual `TMainMenu` component on a form.

Dynamically creating a new `TMainMenu` is doable, but involves message handling to postpone the deletion of the exisiting `TMainMenu` to then be able to create a new one. The reason is that you can not delete a menu in the `OnClick` handler of one of the menu's items.

Let me suggest an easier way to achieve something similar by hiding / showing branches of a single `TMainMenu` as follows:

Drop a `TMainMenu` on the form and write menu items as usual. In my example I created two branches, one named `MenuA` and the other `MenuB`. Under these I added menu items, of which the first one (you are free to choose which one you use) activates the other menu branch and hides it's own branch. And visa versa for the other one.

Here's the menu part of the form in text view:

```
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 112
    Top = 48
    object MenuA: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'MenuA'
      object Item11: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'MenuB'
        OnClick = Item11Click
      end
      object Item12: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Item12'
      end
    end
    object MenuB: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'MenuB'
      object Item21: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'MenuA'
        OnClick = Item21Click
      end
      object Item22: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Item22'
      end
      object Item23: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Item23'
      end
    end
  end
```

And here is the code for the menu clicks. Note that I make the second menu branch hidden in the forms `OnCreate` even. Instead, you can of course set the `Visible` property to `False` at design time, in the `Object Inspector`.

```
procedure TForm9.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MenuB.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TForm9.Item11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MenuB.Visible := True;
  MenuA.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TForm9.Item21Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MenuB.Visible := False;
  MenuA.Visible := True;
end;
```